# CreateProcess fails with error 0

Tags: c++, windows

I want to start a process. To do so I called the CreateProcess method like this:

```
wchar_t *path = (wchar_t*) malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 500);
const char* const_path = "C:/Windows/notepad.exe";
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(const_path); i++)
{
    path[i] = const_path[i];
}

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

if (!CreateProcess(NULL,
    path,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &si,
    &pi))
{
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "Could not start - Code " << GetLastError();
    ui.processStateLabel->setText(s.str().c_str());
    return;
}
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

Problem is: it gives me "Could not start - Code 0", which makes no sense, because error code 0 is successful operation and obviously (no window opened) the operation was not successful. What do I have to do to get this working?

Comment: Terminate your string.

Comment: Noticed it myself like 5 seconds after posting...

Comment: One of the best ways to notice silly errors is to publicly ask for help. :)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but using operator `new[]` would typically be a more "C++-y" way to grab that memory than `malloc`.  Or better yet, `std::make_unique`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that `strlen` Method does not include the 0 termination, which is needed. Thus changing `strlen(const_path)` to `strlen(const_path) + 1` in the for-loop is the solution.

Comment: The more serious problem is that your error reporting is broken.  You have to call GetLastError() before doing else.  Certainly any kind of output since that uses winapi calls under the hood as well and they can easily change the last error code.

Answer (score 3):

As you already figured out, the string is not terminated. You might also want to quote the path.

You should call `GetLastError` before the `std::stringstream` object is created because you don't know what the constructor does under the hood, that will hopefully provide a better error code.